I can't access the server through the local network IP
I don't know much about Linux systems; I'm studying and implementing a CasaOS server on an Ubuntu server. After reserving a LAN IP for the server on my router, I somehow lost access through a specific device. I can access it using the same IP on other devices, and on the device without access, I can still connect through the Tailscale tunnel. How can I solve this problem?
LAN IP of the server:

Trying to connect to the server:


you may find this GiitHub reference of some help. Navigate down the page towards the end.
